# How to clone two hard drives into one

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, clone

Lately when running SMART tests of my hard drives above shows many errors I read a good number of sectors so I decided to buy a new one. The problem is I do not want to have to reinstall my operating system from 0 (Windows and Linux) So, how ow to clone two 80GB hard drives (one with windows and One With Lubuntu) into one of 250gb?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use LiveCD, create partitions on the new hard drive and copy each partition.

another option is to use a tool such as ghost and copy the entire partition.

at the end you have to run fix boot tools -

in windows - fixmbr and fixboot.

in linux - grub-install and update-grub.

you have to make sure both MBR and boot sector of each OS partition are modified.

I would use windows tools and then linux tools because i prefer GRUB boot loader.

found another option - [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) (although i haven't used it):

Comment: have you managed?