# How to clone Ubuntu into same machine with new partion?

Tags: clone

In my computer, I want **more space for Ubuntu.** And for it don't like to format my Ubuntu. How can I **copy everything from present Ubuntu and copy everything with user settings etc into other drive?** ***copy everything but i want change drive space.*** Also I don't want clone entire hard-disk I want clone only one drive by using same machine.
Note:- I have dual boot system. If your answers want other OS no problem. I have another OS is `BOSS Linux` and `scientific Linux`.
configuration:- Present Ubuntu OS have 20GB space. 
and 26 Gb free space with ext4 file system. I want to move my present Ubuntu into that drive?
[image: Ubuntu]

I read
[How to clone two hard drives into one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221057/how-to-clone-two-hard-drives-into-one)
[How to clone to a smaller harddisk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409204/how-to-clone-to-a-smaller-harddisk)
[How To clone harddisk for moving Ubuntu to a new machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358681/how-to-clone-harddisk-for-moving-ubuntu-to-a-new-machine)
[How to clone to a smaller harddisk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409204/how-to-clone-to-a-smaller-harddisk)
[How to clone two hard drives into one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221057/how-to-clone-two-hard-drives-into-one)
[How to clone a user profile on the same computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508274/how-to-clone-a-user-profile-on-the-same-computer)

Comment: you should use `dd` command to clone. for example, `dd if=/dev/sdaX of=/dev/sdaY bs=4; sync`. you should read about `dd` command before you use it

Comment: @edwardtorvalds which os should i use for it? BOSS Linux or scientific linux?

Comment: you should give me more details, output of `lsblk -f` (use paste.ubuntu.com for this) and location of ubuntu, boss linux, scienctific linux and free space in terms of /dev/sdaX

Comment: @edwardtorvalds http://paste.ubuntu.com/11778931/

Comment: you should go with the answer below although this answer wont harm your computer but will be tedious(lengthy process). in case if you change your mind pls let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I not have enough space for my Ubuntu system drive which is I frequently use.
So I want more space and want to back up to avoid anything wrong with my data.But I not have any other storage device to backup.

**First Step:-** By using **`Disk Utility`** , I delete My Scientific Linux drive. For get extra 30 GB space. and make partition 53.GB 
[image: delete partition][image: making partition]
**second Step:-** I **restart Computer**. And start **`BOSS Linux`**.
**3rd Step:-** RUN **DD command** into **BOSS Linux** to make clone of Ubuntu Drive.
[image: dd command]

Before restart PC I install `GRUB loder` into `BOSS Linux`.
[image: grub config] [image: grub install]
Then Start `Ubuntu 14.04` then One problem occurred their. 53GB drive only shows 20GB space. 
[image: drive space pseudo capacity]

Then I use `Gparted utility` to solve it. Again one problem occurred.
 
[image: gparted utility]
[image: critical problem.] 
 solve it run command into terminal.

```
$ e2fsck -f /dev/sda13
```

[image: e2fsck]

I try make `re-size` the drive and re-size successfully. After that I restart again my PC and start Ubuntu for check problem.
 [image: Ubuntu 14 53gb space] problem solved.
 Again start **BOSS Linux** to **format old Ubuntu drive**. Restart PC and select Ubuntu 14.04 and finally install Grub into Ubuntu.And it solve my problem without any other external or internal extra storage devices.
**NOTE:-** But its better and strongly recommend that keep back-up before do it.
 You can be able do it by using Live CD or boot repair disk.   For that I so much thankful of [edward-torvalds](https://askubuntu.com/users/294611/edward-torvalds) and [Helio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/144121/helio) without their valuable info, guidance, and reference it is impossible to solve it for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Helio thanks for proper guidance about Gparted utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a full backup with remastersys. To install it enter the following commands:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mutse-young/remastersys`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install remastersys`

Now set up your user settings:

1. Ppen nautilus file manager as root with this command: `sudo nautilus`.
2. Navigate to your home folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
   to show hidden files and folders.
3. Copy all the contents from your home except the `.cache` folder to `/etc/skel`

Now create a ISO installation file using remastersys.

1. Launch Remastersys from dash.
2. Now create the clone of your Ubuntu machine using remastersys `Backup`.

The backup will be saved in a ISO installer anc can be found in `/home/remastersys`.

Tips:
 1. Move you personal contents such as documents, videos, pictures, downloads etc to somewhere else. or the backup will be too big.
 2. Delete all the .deb files from `/var/cache/apt/archives`. It'll help to reduce the image.

Now Finally burn the image to a DVD or make a bootable pendrive with `Startup Disk Creator` and install it to your desired partition.

Comment: I want transfer files into other drive in real or run time. making iso is not need. and it time consuming process. also I dont want delete anything. I just want make exact copy of data.

Comment: The things I mentioned you to delete will reduce the disk space, you can also do it if you want to increase disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else I recommend to backup your data (/home)  and your config (/etc) to another device!
In your specific case you seem to be trying to migrate from a 20GB partition to a 26GB partition.

If this is about running out of disk space: make the 26 GB your new /home!
and keep the 20GB as / 
Steps necessary:

1. make filesystem (also known as formatting) on the 26GB partition,
   rsync- avz /home/ to the 26GB partition
2. try if it works :mount it to /home
3. if it works think about making it final by editing fstab (find out the
   UUID with the blkid command)

Remember your old /home is still there and uses disk space on the 20GB partition! (At some point you will want to get rid of it - keeping in mind to have a backup. I would give the root user a password, if you mess up you will not be able to sudo anymore! If you can login as root your ~ resides in /root/ and you are still operational without a /home.)

If it is not about running out of disk space:
New install on the 26GB partition an then rsync -avz the /home to the fresh install. (You could stumble upon the need to modify /etc/passwd and /etc/group to provide the correct User and Group IDs)