# Enlarge disk partition after cloning

Tags: partitioning, disk, resize, clone

I have SSD disk 30GB with Ubuntu installation. It is too small, because I have there some servers and projects. Currently, there is about 800MB free space.

I already bought new SSD disk with 120GB. I Would like to clone my disk with Ubuntu live CD.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/"30GBDISK" of=/dev/"120GBDISK"
```

Then I would like to enlarge disk partition, but I am not sure how to do it. I remember that I used gparted in past, but there where some problems with mounting. Should be the gparted run from CD or cloned disk?

Pls, could anyone tell me correct step by step process?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/641319/how-to-clone-ubuntu-into-same-machine-with-new-partion read it may be help you.

Answer (score -1):

After your clone, I would use gparted to resize as needed.

http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions